# load files into a table using loop in SSIS 2008

Tags: ssis

I have to load files into a table using loop in SSIS 2008 ..
  Also need to track each process into  a 'process_track' table containing the fields  Process_id, Start_time, End_time and Status (processing or completed) ..  How can  I do this  ? 
   Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Follow this (one of numerous ones that can be found online) to import multiple files in a folder. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/. In the execute SQL Task, instead of running `EXEC sp_OurSQLTask`, run the parameterised SQL that inserts to your logging table. Try that and post back with a specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

In broad strokes, you want a for loop in your control flow, which will manipulates a variable that you can use in an expression that determines the connection string of your flat file connection manager. In the for loop, have a data flow task that moves your data around, as well as an 'execute sql statement' task which writes an update to your process_track table.

Comment: Sorry , I am new to SSIS , so will you give me clean idea about this task ..?

Comment: As Nick says, check out any of the online materials on FOR loops in SSIS. It's all there. You may want to delve into a textbook on it when you have time. Good luck.